# bilinear form is non-degenerate

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $U=\mathbb{R}^3/\mathbb{R}(1,1,1)$ and let $V=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^3|\sum_{i=1}^3y_i=0\}$. Show that $(x+\mathbb{R}(1,1,1),y)=\sum_{i=1}^3x_iy_i$ defines a non-degenerate bilinear form on $U\times V$.

**Proof**

Fix $x$, the pairing is defined by choosing an arbitrary representative in the equivalent class of $x+\mathbb{R}(1,1,1)$, say $x$, along with $y\in V$ and map them to their dot product. It is linear in $y$ because $(x+\mathbb{R}(1,1,1),\alpha y+\beta)=\sum_{i=1}^3x_i(\alpha y_i+\beta)=\alpha\sum_{i=1}^3x_iy_i+\beta\sum_{i=1}^3x_i$..... The pairing is linear in $x+\mathbb{R}(1,1,1)$ because $(\alpha x+\beta+\mathbb{R}(1,1,1),y)=\sum_{i=1}^3(\alpha x_i+\beta)y_i=\sum_{i=1}^3\alpha x_iy_i+\beta\sum_{i=1}^3y_i$ ......

How should I continue?